# error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar e section_format

Tags: java, android

Estou aprendendo a programar para Android e criei um app do zero em uma tela vazia. Depois, resolvi colocar minha Activity em um modelo com tabs, onde a primeira tab seria essa tela que já fiz e a segunda eu ainda iria programar.
Criei uma Activity em branco com o modelo de tabs e comecei a copiar os códigos dessa nova Activity para o meu projeto. O problema é que agora estou parado em dois erros e não consigo resolver. Já procurei em vários lugares e nada.

Provavelmente é algo simples para vocês, porém como sou novo, não consigo enxergar o problema.

Error:(90, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar e
Error:(523, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable section_format

MainActivity.java:

```
mtoolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

-

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar supportActionBar) {
        this.mtoolbar = supportActionBar; //        this.supportActionBar = supportActionBar;
    }

    public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
        return supportFragmentManager;
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mateuspc1.tab.TabActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vitasbut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/vitas1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gtabut"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vitasbut2"
                ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vitasbut2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/vitas2e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/aiaichoquebut"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vitasbut"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/gtabut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/gta1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bolsbut"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gtabut2"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vitasbut" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/gtabut2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/gta2e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/acertomizbut"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gtabut"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vitasbut2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/gabebut"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/gabe1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gtabut2"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aiaichoquebut" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bolsbut"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/bols1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bolsbut2"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gtabut" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bolsbut2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/bols2e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/aiaichoquebut"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bolsbut"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gtabut2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/acertomizbut"
                android:layout_width="111dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/acertmiz1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bolsbut2"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gabebut" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/aiaichoquebut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/aiaichoque1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gabebut"
                ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vitasbut2"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bnsetimaartebut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bnsetimaarte1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bolsbut" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fausteroubut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fausterou1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bnsetimaartebut"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/onImageGalleryClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fausttapegfogbut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/faustfogo1e2"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bnsetimaartebut" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/onImageGalleryClicked"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:onClick="onImageGalleryClicked"
                android:text="Button"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bnsetimaartebut"
                ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bolsbut2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPicture"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
                ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fausttapegfogbut"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="389dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewConstraint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.656"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No seu ficheiro strings.xml, adicione esta linha:  `<string name="section_format">Tab de numero: %d</string>`

Comment: Oi! Obrigado pela ajuda! erro section_format resolvido. o error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar ainda persiste

Comment: Esse erro está surgindo porque ele não encontra um Toolbar no seu `activity_main.xml`. Você pode postar esse layout na sua pergunta?

Comment: Oi! Encontrei o erro: estava faltando o android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar no meu XML. Obrigado pela ajuda!